# Disabled color state of Material button

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, material-design, android-button

The Material Spec shows a disabled button state that looks greyed out.

https://www.material.io/design/components/buttons.html#toggle-button

I am using the MaterialButton from the material components from Android:
https://www.material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

However when setting the button to disabled the color/tint of the button does not change.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/disabled_material_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="@string/button_label_disabled"/>
```

Just not implemented in Material Android Components by default?  Does Material Components define a disabled button statelist?

Answer (score 90):

1. Create the folder `/res/color` (in your `res` directory).
2. Add a new color resource file here, named something like **color_states_materialbutton.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/colorDisabled"  />
    <item android:color="@color/colorEnabled" />
</selector>
```

3. Create a style in **styles.xml** with one of the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` styles as its parent and your color state list as the `backgrountTint` tag:

```
<style name="MaterialButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/color_states_materialbutton</item>
</style>
```

4. Set your style on the `MaterialButton` in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/MaterialButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/disabled_material_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="@string/button_label_disabled"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer. Also we can use app:backgroundTint="@color/my_color" directly in xml code of button.

Comment: I recommend using `parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Button"` in the style parent to keep button functionality (such as ripple effect) working properly.

Answer (score 27):

With the default style `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` the [default selector](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector.xml#L18) used as [`backgroundTint`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/styles.xml#L44) handles the disabled state without any changes:

It is the default selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:enabled="false"
        ..>
```

[image]

If you want to **change** the disabled color you can use a custom selector

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:backgroundTint="@color/my_selector"
        ..>
```

or you can override the colors used in the default selector:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:theme="@style/button_overlay"
        ..>
```

with:

```
    <style name="button_overlay">
       <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/my_color</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: `<item name="colorOnSurface">@color/my_color</item>` and what does it change for MaterialButton"?

Comment: How do you differentiate the text and the background colors?  I had to make a separate file.  Is there are more direct way?

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new **Android Resource Directory** inside your res folder.  Give it the name "color" (see attached image).
2. Create a Color Resource File with the name "button_disabled" (see attached image).
3. Place the below code into the button_disabled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#FD7E14" android:alpha="0.45"   />
            <item android:color="#FD7E14" />
        </selector>
```

4. Locate your values/styles.xml and add the below code

```
<style name="AppMaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">  <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/button_disabled</item> </style>
```

5. Goto your layout/activity_filename.xml file and add this 
   `android:enabled="false"` to your button widget.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
       android:enabled="false"
       android:id="@+id/button_Join"
       style="@style/AppMaterialButton"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="next" 
       app:cornerRadius="0dp" />
```

[Android Resource Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jNvF.png)

[image: Create a Color Resource File]

Answer (score 0):

you should use a ThemeOverlay and apply the Colored style separately

```
    <style name="AccentButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
         <!-- customize colorButtonNormal for the disable color -->
         <!-- customize colorAccent for the enabled color -->
    </style>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fragment_login_login_button"
        android:theme="@style/AccentButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those looking to change icon and text color in button disabled state, here is how we can do steps are almost same for changing background color.

create a file inside **color/button_enable_disable_state.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:alpha=".3" android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

then go to your them or directly apply to your view like below.

```
  <style name="ButtonStyled" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="iconGravity">textStart</item>
        <item name="iconPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/button_enable_disable_state</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_enable_disable_state</item>
    </style>
```

and apply to your view if using theme like below

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        style="@style/ButtonStyled"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Call"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_call_icon"
       />
```

or directly apply apply to a view like below

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        style="@style/ButtonStyled"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Call"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="@color/button_enable_disable_state"
        app:iconTint="@color/button_enable_disable_state"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_call_icon"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to create enable/disable effect is by overriding the MaterialButton class and apply ColorMatrix on it

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

class MaterialButtonCustom @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): MaterialButton(context,attrs,defStyleAttr) {
    var disabled = false
        set(value) {
            field = value
            requestLayout()
        }

    private val paint = Paint()

    init {
        val cm = ColorMatrix()
        cm.set(
            floatArrayOf(
                0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0f, 0f,
                0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0f, 0f,
                0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0f, 0f,
                0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f
            )
        )
        paint.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm)
    }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        if (disabled) {
            canvas?.saveLayer(null, paint)
        }

        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)

        if (disabled) {
            canvas?.restore()
        }
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        if (disabled) {
            canvas?.saveLayer(null, paint)
        }

        super.draw(canvas)

        if (disabled) {
            canvas?.restore()
        }
    }
}
```

and inside Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var btn_plus:MaterialButtonCustom
    var isActive: Boolean = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn_plus = findViewById(R.id.btn_plus)
        setBtnEnabled()
        btn_plus.setOnClickListener {
            isActive = !isActive
            if(isActive){
                setBtnDisabled()
            }else{
                setBtnEnabled()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun setBtnDisabled() {
        btn_plus.disabled = true
    }

    private fun setBtnEnabled() {
        btn_plus.disabled = false
    }
}
```